# CANoe CAPL-multiple TCP connections

Tags: sockets, capl, canoe

I'm trying to communicate with two devices through ETH. My question is that I need to create two nodes, one socket for each node, or there is the possibility to put both connections inside in a just one node?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple connections from one single node. There is no need to do this from separate nodes.

When you call `TcpOpen` you get back a handle to the socket for this very connection.

When you later call `TcpSend`, `TcpReceive`, and so on, you have to pass in the handle.

Comment: Make sense... I will check my code soon and I will sent you a feedback.
Thanks!

Comment: It works. In order to have some running speed I have used two different nodes for each socket.